# PDOException error in the cakephp 3

Tags: pdo, cakephp-3.0

Cake php 3 error

```
Error Start:

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.
Error End:
```

There is PDOException error when I move the site local to server. I enable the identifier quoting in the `app.php` file. But nothing happened.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solutions for it. Firstly we have need to set true the identifire on in app.php or give the the grant permission to the user. For more detail check this blog. http://www.peakhints.com/pdo-exception-error-cakephp-3/

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Link-only answers aren't generally accepted. [See this help subject](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)